# Python - while loop, call variable

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

How can I call `n` at the end of the script below? 
I keep getting the error " Message: javascript error: n is not defined"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
usr="username"
psw="pass"


n = 1
while n < 10:
    url_list = ['url 1', 'url 2', 'url 3' 'url 10']

    for url in url_list:

                    driver.get('https://%s/' %(url))

                    time.sleep(2)

                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='user']").send_keys(username)
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']").send_keys(pass)
                    driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()

                    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tabn');")
                    driver.switch_to.window("tabn",)
                    n = n + 1
```

In these lines "tab" should increment every cycle, like tab1, tab2, tab3...tab10:

```
                driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '**tabn**');")
                driver.switch_to.window("**tabn**",)
                n = n + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your problem occuring at the line n = n + 1? I don't see how that would be related to javascript. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It's not clear what you want.  You "call" a function; `n` is an integer, and `url` is a string -- you cannot *call* either of those.  If you are simply trying to *access* or *use* their values, then most of your code is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: The problem is related to these 2 lines:
                    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tabn');")
                    driver.switch_to.window("tabn",)
I want "n" after "tab" to increment every cycle.

Comment: use: `"tab%d" % n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code :(By replacing with your existing code)

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab{}');".format(n))
driver.switch_to.window("tab{}".format(n),)
n = n + 1
```

Sample Example :

```
for n in range(5):
    print("window.open('about:blank', 'tab{}');".format(n))
    print("tab{}".format(n),)
    n = n + 1
```

Output :

```
window.open('about:blank', 'tab0');
tab0
window.open('about:blank', 'tab1');
tab1
window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');
tab2
window.open('about:blank', 'tab3');
tab3
window.open('about:blank', 'tab4');
tab4
```

Once you get this you can integrate it with your sselenium Code.